# Counter Value limit to some value then reset to zero

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008, excel-2010

I have the following table:

**Case 1:**

```
Date        Time    Value   Prev_Value    Result1   PurposeResult
6/1/2014    0:00    80,000           
6/1/2014    1:00    82,000  80,000        2,000     2,000
6/1/2014    2:00    83,000  82,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    3:00    84,000  83,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    4:00    85,000  84,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    5:00    86,000  85,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    6:00    87,000  86,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    7:00    88,000  87,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    8:00    89,000  88,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    9:00    90,000  89,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    10:00   91,000  90,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    11:00   92,000  91,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    12:00   93,000  92,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    13:00   94,000  93,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    14:00   95,000  94,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    15:00   96,000  95,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    16:00   97,000  96,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    17:00   98,000  97,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    18:00   99,000  98,000        1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    19:00   0       99,000        -99,000   1,000
6/1/2014    20:00   1,000   0             1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    21:00   2,000   1,000         1,000     1,000
6/1/2014    22:00   3,000   2,000         1,000     1,000
```

**CASE 2:**

```
    Date        Time    Value   Prev_Value    Result1
    6/1/2014    0:00    80,000           
    6/1/2014    1:00    82,000  80,000        2,000     
    6/1/2014    2:00    83,000  82,000        1,000     
    6/1/2014    3:00    84,000  83,000        1,000     
    6/1/2014    4:00    85,000  84,000        1,000     
    6/1/2014    5:00    86,000  85,000        1,000     
    6/1/2014    6:00    87,000  86,000        1,000     
    6/1/2014    7:00    88,000  87,000        1,000     
    6/1/2014    8:00    89,000  88,000        1,000     
    6/1/2014    9:00    0       89,000        -89,000   
    6/1/2014    10:00   1,000   0             1,000     
    6/1/2014    11:00   2,000   1,000         1,000  
    6/1/2014    12:00   3,000   2,000         1,000   
    6/1/2014    13:00   4,000   3,000         1,000  
    6/1/2014    14:00   5,000   4,000         1,000   
    6/1/2014    15:00   6,000   5,000         1,000  
    6/1/2014    16:00   7,000   6,000         1,000 
    6/1/2014    17:00   8,000   7,000         1,000 
    6/1/2014    18:00   9,000   8,000         1,000          
    6/1/2014    19:00   10,000  9,000         1,000          
    6/1/2014    20:00   11,000  10,000        1,000          
    6/1/2014    21:00   12,000  11,000        1,000          
    6/1/2014    22:00   13,000  12,000        1,000
```

Explanation Case 1:
Result1 is coming from, current value subtract prev_value.
The value actually is a counter value. Which is only limit until 99,999. So if only using simple subtract. It will cause an error. If you check it on 19:00 time, the Result1 shouldn't be minus. Then I tried this case on excel. Then I use this formula:

```
=IF((Value - Prev_Value < 0), (100000 + Value) - Prev_Value, Value - Prev_Value)
```

I put the formula above on `PurposeResult` field. So Case 1, it's solved. Which is normal counter until reach the limit.

Now, Explanation Case 2:
It is the same with Case 1, but for some reason the value is not reach the limit. For instance, at 9 o'clock.. It reset to zero. Which means, my formula above won't work.

Just for information, the table only consist of `Date`, `Time`, and `Value`. Below are sample of t-sql to select previous record and get the simple result (current value subtract prev_value)

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT groupid, odate, otime, ovalue,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY groupid ORDER BY odate, otime) rn
  FROM table1
)
SELECT a.groupid, a.odate, a.otime, a.ovalue, b.ovalue Prev_oValue,
       a.ovalue-b.ovalue oResult
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b ON a.groupid = b.groupid AND a.rn = b.rn + 1
ORDER BY a.groupid, a.odate, a.otime
```

So the question is, how can I solve this problem? Excel and SQL of course.

really appreciate for this. Thank you so much.

Comment: what is the desirednresult for case2?

Comment: It should be the same result as case 1.

Comment: then your rule is: if value = 0 then result = 1,000

Comment: which result do you expect for case2 at 9:00?

Comment: @niyou, it should be 0. On 10:00, it should be 1,000

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a 5 digit counter which trips back to show `0` at 100,000 or multiples thereof. Since your data is in order, a drop in the count value relative to the preceding reading would indicate that the counter has tripped. Please try, if `Date` is in A1, in F3 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(C3>C2,C3-C2,C3-C2+100000)
```

This uses only the values in ColumnC to, possibly, avoid the need for ColumnD so the data should be contiguous.

Note that it is the nature of such a counter that 'consumption' of 101,000 from one reading to the next can not be differentiated from 'consumption' of just 1,000 over the same interval.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please put it on your answer with the table..?